# How to uninstall a feature in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-feature

I need to remove a feature completely from SharePoint with all its assemblies, folders and everything.
I found that I can do this by SharePoint management shell, but I don't know how to find, open or download it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sharepoint Management Shell comes with Sharepoint and is simply a PowerShell Add-In which you could load manually. If you don't have the Sharepoint Management Shell you can also use `stsadm.exe`.

For uninstalling via Powershell:

- [Installing or Uninstalling Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442691.aspx)

For uninstalling via stsadm:

- [Uninstallfeature: Stsadm operation (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262976%28office.12%29.aspx)

You can find the Sharepoint Management Shell in the start menu, the stsadm you can find in the Sharepoint installation folder.

For a list of all installed features run the following command in PowerShell:

```
Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property Scope,DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName,Id
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can remember the exact name/path of the feature. Isn't there a way to see that visually?

Comment: There sure is: `Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property Scope,DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName,Id` - also check out http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/08/powershell-commands-to-list-sharepoint-features.html

Comment: since this is SP 2007, is the Sharepoint Management Shell an option or will Ahmad need to use stsadm?

Comment: Well the Sharepoint Management Shell is not installed by default with MOSS2007 as far as I remember, but it is certainly usable and actually advised by MS to be used

Comment: If you want to enumerate features via STSADM there is a small code snippet here: http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/enumerate-features.html